# Cabeçalhos do relatório mão aparecem no Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Ativei a opção de "Mostrar todos os cabeçalhos em pesquisa detalhada" no meu relatório, mas quando abro uma pesquisa detalhada, não aparecem nem os cabeçalhos, nem os rodapés.

Segue a estrutura do meu relatório:

```
--Cabeçalho do Relatório
  --Cabeçalho da página
    --Cabeçalho do grupo <- Onde eu detalho a pesquisa
      --Detalhes (Oculto - Sem pesquisa detalhada)
    --Rodapé do grupo (Oculto - Sem pesquisa detalhada)
  --Rodapé da página
--Rodapé do relatório
```

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afinal, o caminho é o mesmo, mas em outro lugar.
Precisei também ativar a mesma opção em:

```
Crystal Reports > Report > Report Options... > Mostrar todos os cabeçalhos em pesquisa detalhada
```

Havia apenas ativado a opção em:

```
Crystal Reports > Design > Default Settings...
```